# Callbacks Events on Cakephp 3.x when using Update()

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I know that `updateAll()` doesn't trigger afterSave/beforeSave events. But I need them. So I tried de following code:

```
//On my Model
$tbTU = TableRegistry::get('TaskUser');
$MyQuery = $tbTU->query()->where(["My rule here"]);
foreach ($MyQuery as $tu) {
  $e->update()->set([
    'status' => 3,
    'user_id' => NULL,
    'modified' => Time::now()
  ])
  ->where(['TaskUser.id' => $tu->id])
  ->execute();
}
return;
```

Here is my afterSave() on TaskUser table:

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options) {

      debug($entity);
      exit;
}
```

The code works, but the afterSave event never get called. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Check to make sure that `$tbTU` really is the type you think it is, not the generic Cake table class. If it is, then maybe share your `afterSave` implementation with us.

Comment: I think that $tbTU is the right type. Just added the afterSave method.

Comment: What is `$e` in your code?

Comment: Any answers on this? Does afterSave() work for update()?